# vscode jump to git/source control shortcut/command for current file

Tags: visual-studio-code

Just wondering if anyone knows if there is a shortcut or command in vscode that will jump the current file to the source control tab?

I know that if you're in source control, `cmd + ;` will jump you to the file alone, but if you want to get back to the source control view, is there a reverse command?

Thanks!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can add a keyboard shortcut to jump to git changes view like so:

```
{
  "key": "shift+cmd+;",
  "command": "git.openChange"
},
{
  "key": "cmd+;",
  "command": "git.openFile"
}
```

then you can use `cmd+;` from within a file to jump to its git changes and `shift+cmd+;` to jump back.